# Difference between AllowedHosts in appsettings.json and UseCors in .NET Core API 3.x

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I see that .NET Core 3.x comes with a new special configuration **AllowedHosts** used to list hosts allowed to access the site while this option already exists with CORS (app.UseCors).

What's the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-filtering), `allowedHosts` is used for host filtering to bind your app to specific hostnames. For example, if you replace following:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

with

```
"AllowedHosts": "example.com"
```

and you try to access your app using `http://localhost:xxxx/` address you will get default bad request (400) response.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </ HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Because of the host-filtering middleware not allowing the app to bind the app to any other hostname except `example.com`.

### CORS

CORS, on the other hand, is to control which 'external' origins (i.e. websites) browsers should allow to load & read resources from your app or API.

Comment: Technically speaking CORS isn't going to disallow calls to the API, but it disallows the browser to render the response. The call is still made.

Comment: can we add multiple entries to the allowed hosts section as comma separated or something? like "localhost,devserver.domain" or something like that?

Comment: @Ak777 yes, you can. The value is a semicolon-delimited list of host names without port numbers, e.g. `example.com;localhost`.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot In which situation this can be helpfull ?

Comment: What exactly does having `"AllowedHosts": "example.com"` do? Like does it prevent some sort of attack?

Comment: how about IpAddresses ITest something `"AllowedHosts": "localhost;1xx.7x.82x.53x"`  like but its not worked

Comment: @RaminAzali As the property name suggest, `AllowedHosts` requires hostnames, not IP addresses. It does not say `AllowedIP` for a reason.

Comment: Doesn't CORS "disallow" the call in the sense that a CORS pre-flight request will be sent which, if negative, will result in the actual API call NOT being made - I think that's what we expect browsers to to do?